Calculation of Average Queue Length in a Simple Queueing Model
Why does the average queue length in a single-queue system tend to infinity when the average number of arrivals equals the average number of departures?
Define the queue model parameters:
λ: Average arrival rate, which is the rate at which customers or tasks arrive per unit of time.
μ: Average service rate, which is the rate at which customers or tasks are served per unit of time.
So when λ=μ, why does the queue length tend to infinity?
Why does the queue length tend to infinity? Can the queue be a finite value?

You can intuitively understand it like this: as more time progresses, the more variance we see in the combination of arrivals and service times (averages are still the constants like you said). Initially the queue remains constant sized, but some rapid arrivals may increase it by some size $k_0$, then some rapid services might decrease it by $k_1 > k_0$, then it remains constant, etc.As services stop when queue length is $0$, after a long enough time, we can get arbitrary long queues
